# inserting data throught one to one relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi i am new to laravel please tell mi how to perform data insertion in one to one relationship

Model 1

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class employee_attendence extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable  = array('is_present' ,'date');
    //protected $fillable=[];
    public $timemstamps= false ;

    public function employee_data(){
            //return $this->hasOne(employee_data::class,'App/employee_data');
        return $this->hasOne('App/employee_data', 'user_id', 'id');

    }
}
```

Model2

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class employee_data extends Model
{
    //protected $fillabel=['first_name','last_name','contact_no','date_joining','post'];

    protected $fillable  = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'contact_no' ,'date_joining','post' );
    //protected $fillable=[];
    public $timemstamps= false ;

    public function employee_attendence()
    {
            //return $this->hasOne( employee_attendence::class, 'App/employee_attendence');
            return $this->hasOne('App/employee_attendence', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

controller

```
    public function mark_Attendence()
    {
        $data = employee_data::all();
        return view('attendence', compact('data', $data));
    } 


    public function Attendence($id)
    {

        //$user=employee_attendence::find(1);
       // $user = App\employee_attendence::has("user_id")->with("user_id")->get();

       /* $employee= array(
    'is_present' => $request->is_present,
    'date'=> $request->date

     );*/

        $employee = new employee_attendence([
            'is_present' => $request->get('is_present'),
            'date' => $request->get('date')

            ]);


        $employee->save();
        //employee_attendence::whereId($id)->create($employee);
        //$data=employee_attendence::findOrFail($id)->updateOrCreate([],['is_present' => 'present']);
        return redirect('/index')->with('succ','Attendence added successfully');
       // echo "attendence:" .$user;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like so:

For `employee_data`:

```
$employee = new employee_attendence([
        'is_present' => $request->get('is_present'),
        'date' => $request->get('date')

        ]);


    $employee->save();
    $employee->employee_data()->create([]);
```

Same can be done for `employee_attendance` like `->employee_attendance()->create([]);`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Employee\
Error
Class 'App/employee_data' not found
http://localhost:8080/Employee/mark_attendence?date=2020-05-13&is_present=Present

Comment: for some reason it cant find your model. confirm if you are using it right. in `employee_data()` relationship in `employee_attendance` model try giving `employee_data::class` instead of `'App/employee_data'`.

Comment: Thanks alot !!
it is inserting attendence data into databse but throwing error on the page while executing/implementing